# Oracle Full Text Search

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

Which data type in Oracle 10 and 11g is best suited for full text search to be conducted on. I am thinking BLOB?

Answer (score 1):

It could be `varchar2`, `clob`, or `blob`. It depends on the size of a chunk of text that will be in a record. docs: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm

**EDIT** here's a basic introduction http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/FullTextIndexingUsingOracleText9i.php